# Matrix exponential - From given Infinite series result

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

**Given Data in the question**

1. We have a recursion and its sum defined as follows

$ \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
   R_0(t)=I_{3 \times 3}  & \mbox{if } n = 0 \\
   R_1(t)=tR_0  \hspace{.1cm} A & \mbox{if }n=1\\
        R_{n+2}(t)=\frac{t}{n+2}\{ R_{n+1}(t)\hspace{.1cm}A+ t\hspace{.1cm} R_{n}(t)\hspace{.1cm}B\} & \mbox{if }n>= 2\\
 \end{array}
\right. \tag 1$

$e^{\Omega(t)}=R(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} R_n(t)= I + tIA + \frac{t^2}{2}IA^2+\frac{t^2}{2} IB + \frac{t^3}{3\times 2}IA^3+\frac{t^3}{3\times 2}IBA+\frac{t^3}{3}IAB +....+..+ \tag 2$

2. $A,B ,I$ are constant matrices with dimension $3\times 3$.
3. A,B are skew symmetric matrices. I is Identity matrix
4. General expansion of matrix exponent is given by
   $  \exp(\tau)=\sum{}\frac{\tau^k}{k!} \tag 3$
5. $\frac{\mathrm{d} e^{\Omega(t))}}{\mathrm{d} t}= (A+Bt)e^{\Omega(t)} \tag 4$
6. $ e^{\Omega(t)}$ is a rotation matrix. Means orthogonal with determinant 1

**Question**

1. How do we extract the value of skew symmetric $\Omega(t)$ from the given expansion   above(equation 2)?

Comment: Is your $I$ not the identity matrix?  If it isn't, that's really bad choice of notation!

Comment: Yes It is Identity matrix . I have added explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can't, without more assumptions, because $\exp$ is not one-to-one.  But if you assume $\Omega(t)$ is analytic with $\Omega(0) = I$, then you can use the fact that (this branch of) 
$$\ln(I+X) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} X^j $$
for small $X$.

EDIT: You might find this useful.  If a $3 \times 3$ matrix $R$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$, then $R = e^{\Omega}$ where 
$\Omega = a I + b R + c R^2$ and $a,b,c$ are the solutions of the system
$a + b \lambda_i + c \lambda_i^2 = \log(\lambda_i)$.  Since your $e^\Omega(t)$
is a rotation matrix and $\Omega(0) = 0$, the $\lambda_i$ will be $1, e^{i\theta(t)}, e^{-i\theta(t)}$ for some real $\theta$, with $\theta(0) = 0$.
I get 
$$ a=-{\frac {\theta\, \left( 2\,\cos \left( \theta
 \right) +1 \right) }{2\;\sin \left( \theta \right) }},b={\frac {\theta\,
 \left( \cos \left( \theta \right) +1 \right) }{\sin \left( \theta
 \right) }},c=-{\frac {\theta}{2\;\sin \left( \theta \right) }}
$$

EDIT: Assuming $A \ne 0$, we can assume wlog (by choosing our unit of time and our coordinate system) that $$A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & -1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 0\cr}$$
Then I get
$$
\eqalign{\Omega &= t A + 
\dfrac{t^2}{2} B + \dfrac{t^3}{12} \pmatrix{0 &-b_{23} & 0\cr b_{23} & 0 & b_{12}\cr 0 & -b_{12} & 0\cr } \cr &+ \dfrac{t^5}{720} \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-3\,b_{{1,2}}b_{{1,3}}-b_{{2,3}}&3\,{b_{
{1,2}}}^{2}+3\,{b_{{2,3}}}^{2}\\ 3\,b_{{1,2}}b_{{1,3
}}+b_{{2,3}}&0&-3\,b_{{1,3}}b_{{2,3}}+b_{{1,2}}\\ -3
\,{b_{{1,2}}}^{2}-3\,{b_{{2,3}}}^{2}&3\,b_{{1,3}}b_{{2,3}}-b_{{1,2}}&0
\end {array} \right) \cr
&+ \dfrac{t^6}{720} \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&b_{{1,3}}b_{{2,3}}&0
\\ -b_{{1,3}}b_{{2,3}}&0&-b_{{1,2}}b_{{1,3}}
\\ 0&b_{{1,2}}b_{{1,3}}&0\end {array} \right)\cr
&+ \dfrac{t^7}{30240} \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-6\,{b_{{1,2}}}^{2}b_{{2,3}}-6\,{b_{{1,3
}}}^{2}b_{{2,3}}-6\,{b_{{2,3}}}^{3}-3\,b_{{1,2}}b_{{1,3}}-b_{{2,3}}&4
\,{b_{{1,2}}}^{2}+4\,{b_{{2,3}}}^{2}\\ 6\,{b_{{1,2}}
}^{2}b_{{2,3}}+6\,{b_{{1,3}}}^{2}b_{{2,3}}+6\,{b_{{2,3}}}^{3}+3\,b_{{1
,2}}b_{{1,3}}+b_{{2,3}}&0&6\,{b_{{1,2}}}^{3}+6\,b_{{1,2}}{b_{{1,3}}}^{
2}+6\,{b_{{2,3}}}^{2}b_{{1,2}}-3\,b_{{1,3}}b_{{2,3}}+b_{{1,2}}
\\ -4\,{b_{{1,2}}}^{2}-4\,{b_{{2,3}}}^{2}&-6\,{b_{{1
,2}}}^{3}-6\,b_{{1,2}}{b_{{1,3}}}^{2}-6\,{b_{{2,3}}}^{2}b_{{1,2}}+3\,b
_{{1,3}}b_{{2,3}}-b_{{1,2}}&0\end {array} \right) \cr
&+ O(t^8)
}
$$

Comment: I have added one more assumptions $\frac{\mathrm{d} e^{\Omega(t))}}{\mathrm{d} t}= (A+Bt)e^{\Omega(t)}$

Comment: $\Omega(0)=0$ will cancel lot of terms in the recursion. You may loose entire property too

Comment: I have addded more assumptions please check

Comment: Sorry, typo: it should have been $\Omega(0) = I$.

Comment: It is already given that $R(t)$ is a rotation matrix. And it is also given the solution of it using infinite series.. So there must be one $\Omega(t)$ which is a skew symmetric matrix. Because every rotation matrix can be represented by the matrix exponent of skew symmetric matrix.

Comment: Sir,do you know the proof of solution of $ \frac{d^2f}{dz^2} + \left(\tilde{a}z^2+\tilde{b}z+\tilde{c}\right)f=0 \tag 5 $  then we get somthing useful. Beacuse by taking one more differentiation on  equation(4) will give such a form